# Overflow in numpy.exp()

Tags: python, numpy, overflow, exponential, exp

I have to calculate the exponential of the following array for my project:

```
w  = [-1.52820754859, -0.000234000845064, -0.00527938881237, 5797.19232191, -6.64682108484,
       18924.7087966, -69.308158911, 1.1158892974, 1.04454511882, 116.795573742]
```

But I've been getting overflow due to the number 18924.7087966.

The goal is to avoid using extra packages such as bigfloat (except "numpy") and get a close result (which has a small relative error).

1.So far I've tried using higher precision (i.e. float128):

```
def getlogZ_robust(w):

    Z = sum(np.exp(np.dot(x,w).astype(np.float128)) for x in iter_all_observations())
    return np.log(Z)
```

But I still get "inf" which is what I want to avoid.

2. I've tried clipping it using nump.clip():

   ```
   def getlogZ_robust(w):

       Z = sum(np.exp(np.clip(np.dot(x,w).astype(np.float128),-11000, 11000)) for x in iter_all_observations())
       return np.log(Z)
   ```

But the relative error is too big.

Can you help me solving this problem, if it is possible?

Comment: Can you use SciPy?  If so, check out [`logsumexp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.logsumexp.html).  If not, you can grab the source code from https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/special/_logsumexp.py, or search a bit here on stackoverflow.  There are probably many implementations of the same method scattered about stackoverflow answers.

Comment: I can't use SciPy, but I've checked out logsumexp and found out that numpy also has a similar function called 'logaddexp' which computes logaddexp(x1, x2) == log(exp(x1) + exp(x2)) without explicitly computing the intermediate exp() values. This way it avoids the overflow. So thank you after all.

Answer (score 4):

Only significantly extended or arbitrary precision packages will be able to handle the huge differences in numbers. The exponential of the largest and most negative numbers in `w` differ by 8000 (!) orders of magnitude. `float` (i.e. double precision) has 'only' 15 digits of precision (meaning `1+1e-16` is numerically equal to 1), such that adding the small numbers to the huge exponential of the largest number has no effect. As a matter of fact, `exp(18924.7087966)` is so huge, that it dominates the sum. Below is a script performing the sum with extended precision in `mpmath`: the ratio of the sum of exponentials and `exp(18924.7087966)` is basically `1`.

```py
w  = [-1.52820754859, -0.000234000845064, -0.00527938881237, 5797.19232191, -6.64682108484,
       18924.7087966, -69.308158911, 1.1158892974, 1.04454511882, 116.795573742]

u = min(w)
v = max(w)

import mpmath
#using plenty of precision
mpmath.mp.dps = 32768
print('%.5e' % mpmath.log10(mpmath.exp(v)/mpmath.exp(u)))
#exp(w) differs by 8000 orders of magnitude for largest and smallest number

s = sum([mpmath.exp(mpmath.mpf(x)) for x in w])

print('%.5e' % (mpmath.exp(v)/s))
#largest exp(w) dominates such that ratio over the sums of exp(w) and exp(max(w)) is approx. 1
```

Answer (score 4):

If the issues of loosing digits in the final results due to hugely different orders of magnitudes of added terms in not a concern, one could also mathematically transform the `log` of sums over exponentials the following way avoiding `exp` of large numbers:

```
log(sum(exp(w)))
= log(sum(exp(w-wmax)*exp(wmax)))
= wmax + log(sum(exp(w-wmax)))
```

In python:

```py
import numpy as np
v = np.array(w)
m = np.max(v)
print(m + np.log(np.sum(np.exp(v-m))))
```

Note that `np.log(np.sum(np.exp(v-m)))` is numerically zero as the exponential of the largest number completely dominates the sum here.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy has a function called [logaddexp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logaddexp.html) which computes

```
logaddexp(x1, x2) == log(exp(x1) + exp(x2))
```

without explicitly computing the intermediate exp() values. This way it avoids the overflow. So here is the solution:

```
def getlogZ_robust(w):

    Z = 0
    for x in iter_all_observations():
        Z = np.logaddexp(Z, np.dot(x,w))
    return Z
```